# Sub-class a control

Tags: c#, subclass, keyboard-events

So I know how to create sub-classes and call them, however I get lost when I have to call / use a sub-class of a control: For example:

```
   public class KeyboardButton : Button
    {
        public void SimulateButtonDown()
        {
            this.OnMouseDown(new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 0, 1, 1, 0));
        }

        public void SimulateButtonUp()
        {
            this.OnMouseUp(new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 0, 1, 1, 0));
        }
    }
```

As created in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441089/c-sharp-winforms-programatically-display-buttons-hover-state).
How to I put to use especially when I have multiple control buttons I want to call the method "SimulateButtonDown()".

Comment: i dont undertand your question, but i think you need change all system.windows.forms.buttons to your inherited class KeyboardButton, then all buttons has the new methods

Comment: Now I understand your response @henocsalinas AFTER reading through michael-gunter 's response below. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using WinForms or WPF? For the sake of this answer, I will assume WinForms.

First, add the code you've posted here into your WinForms project somewhere. Then compile it. After doing so, `KeyboardButton` should be automatically added to your Toolbox. Open a form or user control in the designer of Visual Studio, and you should see a section called "YourProjectName Components". This section should have `KeyboardButton` in it. Just drag and drop it onto your form or user control.

If you want to replace existing buttons on existing forms or user controls, it may be easier to update the code in `xxx.Designer.cs`. (NOTE: EXERCISE CAUTION WHEN EDITING xxx.Designer.cs FILES.) In the Solution Explorer, find the form or user control that has the button(s) you want to replace. Expand the node for the form/user control, and you should see a file called something like `Form1.Designer.cs`. Double-click to open that file. In there, for each existing button, you should see lines such as `this.saveButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();`. Replace `System.Windows.Forms.Button` with `YourNamespace.KeyboardButton`. You will also see lines like `private System.Windows.Forms.Button saveButton;`. Replace the namespace & class name there too.

Once you've got a `KeyboardButton` on your form/user control, you can call `SimulateButtonDown` and `SimulateButtonUp` from within your form/user control just by writing code like `saveButton.SimulateButtonUp()`.